# Convert string with hex values to byte array

Tags: c#, string, arrays

I have this:

```
string x = "0X65 00 0X94 0X81 00 0X40 0X7E 00 0XA0 0XF0 00 0X80 0X2C 00 0XA9 0XA";
```

And I would like this:

```
byte[] x = {0X65, 00, 0X94, 0X81, 00, 0X40, 0X7E, 00, 0XA0, 0XF0, 00, 0X80, 0X2C, 00, 0XA9, 0XA};
```

When I try something like:

```
string[] t = x.split(' ');
byte[] byte = new byte[t.Legnth];
for (int i = 0; i < byte.Length; i++)
            {
                byte[i] = Convert.ToByte(t[i]);
            }
```

the byte is encoded to some other value. I'm not familiar with byte formats, I'm just trying to go directly from a string of bytes separated by a space to having them in the array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Microsoft website: [Convert.ToByte Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified base to
>   an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer.

In this case you need to tell *ToByte* method to convert the string from [base 16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

```
byte[] t = x.Split().Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```